# How to get a value from select with Ajax and use in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

As I wrote in the title I have this part of code in page page.php that is in a subfolder admin. So the path of page is ../admin/page.php:

```
<select name="my_select" id="my_select" onchange="function(this.value);">
                <?php
                    include "../db/db_config.php";

                    $conn = mysql_connect($host,$user,$password)or die(mysql_error());

                    mysql_select_db($db, $conn);
                    $query="Query";
                    $res=mysql_query($query,$conn);
                    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
                        $id=$row['id'];
                        $text=$row['text'];
                        echo "<option value='$id'>$text</option>";
                        }
                    }
                ?>
              </select>
    $var = $_POST['my_select'];
    echo "I have selected $var";
```

I use a function that I have found on internet:

```
function fetch_select(val)
          {
             $.ajax({
               type: 'post',
               url: 'page.php',
               data: {
                 get_option:val
               },
               success: function (response) {
                 document.getElementById("my_select").innerHTML=response; 
               }
             });
          }
```

What I have to do to take value in $var? Because I need this value to build other things. Is it possible?

EDIT:
Probably I don't explain very well my problem. I don't have very good with ajax because I never use it. I have a deadline so I can't study it now. 
Now I have this situation:
I have a select-form with an input submit. After click on the button I use $_POST['myoption'] and I get the value.
Then I do it:

```
if($var == 1)
//a query from database
else if($var == 2)
//another different query
else
//other but no query
```

This work correctely. I need to change it and use in the same page. How can I do the same?

Comment: Shouldn't `$var1` be `$id`

Comment: it's not clear to me what you're trying to achieve.  is the first block of code on a separate page?  if so, you can't do what you're attempting to do.  you can't get a select value that resides on a separate page.  who is selecting the value on that page ???  maybe clarify your intent and what results you expect to see.

Comment: what should the javascript function do?

Comment: I want to take the value in the same page. @fluinc yes I made a mistake but I change it

Comment: @devlin carnate I have a select. I want that the option value selected arrive in a variable PHP. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You don't to do a POST to do this you can do it with jQuery.

```
<?php
include "../db/db_config.php";

$conn = mysql_connect($host,$user,$password)or die(mysql_error());

mysql_select_db($db, $conn);
$query="Query";
$res=mysql_query($query,$conn);
?>

<select name="my_select" id="my_select">

    <?php
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
        $id=$row['id'];
        $text=$row['text'];
        echo "<option value='$id'>$text</option>";
    }
    ?>
</select>
<span id="selected"></span>

<script>
$("#my_select").change(function() {
    $("#selected").html($("#my_select option:selected").text());
});
</script>
```

This will give the select value to PHP:

```
<?php
include "../db/db_config.php";

$conn = mysql_connect($host,$user,$password)or die(mysql_error());

mysql_select_db($db, $conn);
$query="Query";
$res=mysql_query($query,$conn);

if (isset($_POST['my_select'])) {
    $var = $_POST['my_select'];
} else {
    $var = '';
}
?>
<form id="my_form" action="" method="POST">
    <select name="my_select" id="my_select">

        <?php
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
            $id=$row['id'];
            $text=$row['text'];
            echo "<option value='$id'>$text</option>";
        }
        ?>
    </select>
</form>
<span id="selected">I have selected <?php echo $var; ?></span>

<script>
$("#my_select").change(function() {
    $('#my_form').submit();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Ok! Can I put the value in a $var PHP?

Comment: This will work just fine. I would just move the db connection part out from the `<select>`.

Comment: To give the selected option back to PHP you will have to preform a POST or GET via ajax or a form.

Comment: @fluinc I try to do with ajax. But probably I made mistake. Is the function that I have posted ajax? I search on internet

Comment: Try the second one I posted

Comment: It does no work! It reload the page! It's similar to mine!

Comment: PHP is only run on the server. So when the page is loaded into the browser there is no more PHP. That is why the refresh happens.

Comment: What is different between simple method post?